# Maven assembly not behave well when using snapshot dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

This is my sub pom file:
http://pastebin.com/euECBcRx

And there is a main pom file:
http://pastebin.com/JmwczN2v

What I want is packing a jar with dependencies. And in the sub pom file, there's a dependency whose artifactId is jedis.

The problem is: when I change this dependency from a release version to a snapshot version(e.g. 2.0.0 to 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT), **the resulting jar will be incomplete**(no dependency classes involved, just the classes of itself). Why?

(I can get a jar with no error in maven command line output using **both** version)

The release jar and the snapshot jar of the dependency are in different repositories, does that trouble?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running your build with `-X` flag set ? If so, what did it output ?

Comment: First i see two issues in the pom: First repository definition in pom's is bad practice furthermore you don't define the plugin version via pluginManagement. I assume you are talking about the redis.clients:redis artifact? The only versions which exist in central are version 2.1.0. which means you need to configure to have access to the snapshot repository for the jedis artifact or be more accurate to their repository. If so you need to change your configuration of you repository manager to solve that problem. And of course an output via mvn -X would help a lot.

Comment: @Riduidel The output is much too long, so I pasted it in github. There're 5  warnings but I'm not sure any of those matters.

Comment: @khmarbaise 1. I used local repository which contains the snapshot jar(see the main pom file through the second link above); 2. I think maven is capable of getting the jar from my local repository because there is no error during maven execution. But how can I find the real problem?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to paste the link of maven output file! It's on https://raw.github.com/eniu9350/YCSB/master/1.txt